# Export integer values from Node.js C++ module

Tags: node.js

I am writing a C++ module for Node.js that wraps a C library, so we can use the C library from JavaScript.  One of the functions in the C library takes an enum parameter, with the enum values included in the corresponding header file.  I would like to export the enum values as integers from the C++ module so the Node.js application wouldn't have to hardcode the value.  Here is the basic idea:

C:

```
typedef enum 
{
    LOGLEVEL_ERROR = 0,
    LOGLEVEL_WARN,
    LOGLEVEL_INFO
} log_level_t;

write_to_log(log_level_t level, char* message);
```

C++:

```
Logger::Write(int level, char* message)
{
    write_to_log(level, message);
}
```

Node.js:

```
// This is what I want:
logger.write(logger.ERROR, "Oh no!  Something bad happened.");
```

How do I expose `LOGLEVEL_ERROR` from C++ so I can use `logger.ERROR` in JS?  (I would even be OK with `logger.LOGLEVEL_ERROR` in JS.)  I found an old Node.js native module that used a macro `EXPORT_INT32` but this doesn't seem to exist anymore (I'm using Node.js 0.8.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
Local<Object> instance = constructor->NewInstance(2, argv);

Local<Object> logLevel = Object::New();
logLevel->Set(String::NewSymbol("ERROR"), cvv8::CastToJS(LOGLEVEL_ERROR), ReadOnly);
logLevel->Set(String::NewSymbol("WARN"), cvv8::CastToJS(LOGLEVEL_WARN), ReadOnly);
logLevel->Set(String::NewSymbol("INFO"), cvv8::CastToJS(LOGLEVEL_INFO), ReadOnly);

instance->Set(String::NewSymbol("Level"), logLevel, ReadOnly);
```

Then from JavaScript you can access `logger.Level.ERROR`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the number, like this:

```
HandleScope scope;

/** method code here **/

Local<Number> num = Number::New(5);
return scope.Close(num);
```

See my module `kexec` as an example: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec/blob/master/src/kexec.cc

**Edit:** Ooops, I didn't entirely read your question clearly. I would declared those values in JS.

**Edit 2:** Upon further inspection, it seems that it may be a bit harry, but possible. It seems that you might want to use [V8 Juice](http://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/).

Here is the relevant section: [Converting Enums](http://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/wiki/ConvertingTypes#Converting_Enums)

Hope this helps some, but the easiest route would be to just declare them in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using V8Convert but haven't look at V8Juice yet, I'll check that out.  Although putting the values in JS probably will turn out to be the easiest...